# Optionals in swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm watching all the swift tutorials from Apple, but I'm having problems with one of the examples:

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
    var address: Address?
}

class Address {
    var buildingNumber: String? = "234"
    var streetName: String? = "Main St."
    var appartmentNumber: String?
}

let paul = Person()
var addressNumber: Int?

addressNumber = paul.residence?.address?.buildingNumber?.toInt()

if let number = addressNumber {
    "correct"
} else {
    "fault"
}
```

It's always printing out "fault". Is there something painfully obvious I'm missing?

Comment: What is `if let number = addressNumber`?  Is that an assignment?  Does "fault" indicate that the assignment is failing?

Comment: Yup, to begin with, `residence` is never assigned to a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are never actually creating a valid `Residence` or `Address`, if you change your code to:

```
class Person {
    // actually create a residence object
    var residence: Residence? = Residence()
}

class Residence {
    // actually create a address object
    var address: Address? = Address()
}

class Address {
    // ...
}

let paul = Person()
var addressNumber: Int?

// Before Paul was never assigned a valid residence, now one will be created
addressNumber = paul.residence?.address?.buildingNumber?.toInt()

if let number = addressNumber {
    "correct"
} else {
    "fault"
}
// gives you `correct`
```

then it should work great!

Comment: That really was painfully obvious. Thank you, and everyone else who pointed it out!

Comment: @Nilzone- yup, no problem! It happens to all of us at one point or another!

Answer (score 2):

```
let paul = Person()
```

You do nothing else to `paul` including setting his optional residence variable. So in the next line of code, you are accessing `paul`'s residence which is `nil`.

```
addressNumber = paul.residence?.address?.buildingNumber?.toInt()
                      ^ failing right here, residence? returns nil
```

So with optional chaining, this entire expression returns `nil`, so when compared in your next `if let` statement, it is false. This is why the `else` clause is being executed.

Answer (score 2):

Think it through, one step at a time. Particularly, your optional chaining:

`addressNumber = paul.residence?.address?.buildingNumber?.toInt()`

Ask yourself:

1. What is `paul`?
2. What is `paul`'s `residence` property set to?
3. What is the `address` of `paul`'s `residence`?

*Hint: You shouldn't make it past step 2.*

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize anything except `Person()`, so the `residence` property on `paul` is `nil`.

So, in the following optional chain:

```
addressNumber = paul.residence?.address?.buildingNumber?.toInt()
                              ^ you get nil here and don't continue
```

This means that `addressNumber` is `nil`.